# How can I use authenticated websockets with Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, websocket, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt application that fetches data from my backend using an authenticated API, which is called using Nuxt Axios and Auth. I want to use WebSockets in this application and would want to send the authentication headers with the WebSockets to interact with the backend. How can I do so?

Comment: What headers do you want to send and why you want to use WebSockets ?!

Comment: I want to send authentication token for a chat app